# Open API swagger does not work for spring boot Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, api-gateway

I have implemented open api swagger documentation in Api Gateway for my spring boot microservices so that all the swagger links can be loaded from the Gateway itself. Below is my configuration in the Gateway

```
server:
  port: 8085
spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY-SERVICE
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: DEMO-SERVICE
          uri: http://localhost:8083
          predicates:
            - Path=/service-1-aug/**
         - id: UI
          uri: http://localhost:3000
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
springdoc:
  enable-native-support: true
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: true
    path: /swagger-ui.html
    config-url: /v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    urls:
      - url: /v3/api-docs
        name: API Gateway Service
        primaryName: API Gateway Service
      - url: /service-1-aug/v3/api-docs
        name: Service 1 Aug Service
        primaryName: Product Service
```

And this is the dependency I have used

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.0.2'.
```

The documentation is loading if I remove the gateway mapping for the UI service ie

```
        - id: UI
          uri: http://localhost:3000
          predicates:
            - Path=/**.
```

If I add the above lines then the documentation does not load .Can some one tell me how can I fix this.